# Rejecting invocation, expected 74 argument registers, method signature has 75 or more

Tags: android, kotlin

My android app was working fine until I make the following change. The change I made is, I added more editTexts to the Add Item activity and more texView to show them in the Item Details Activity. However, the app crashes on launch with the following error. The activities where I made the changes, Add Item and Item Details, are not called on launching the app. So I do not know why is my app crashing and what wrong I did. Can somebody help me find my mistake?

I am using `Kotlin`

```
    2021-09-05 18:44:25.586 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abc.xyz, PID: 11239
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.abc.xyz.models.Product: void com.abc.xys.models.Product.<init>() failed to verify: void com.abc.xyz.models.Product.<init>(): [0x2D7] Rejecting invocation, expected 74 argument registers, method signature has 75 or more
2021-09-05 18:44:25.586 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime:  void com.abc.xyz.models.Product.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Str
2021-09-05 18:44:25.587 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: ing, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.Date, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker) failed to verify: void com.abc.xyz.models.Product.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java
2021-09-05 18:44:25.587 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: .lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.Date, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker): [0xFE6] Rejecting invocation, expected 63 argument registers, method signature has 64 or more
2021-09-05 18:44:25.587 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime:  com.abc.xyz.models.Product com.abc.xyz.models.Product.copy$default(com.abc.xyz.models.Product, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String,java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Strin
2021-09-05 18:44:25.587 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: g, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String,java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.Date, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, java.lang.Object) failed to verify: com.abc.xyz.models.Product com.abc.xyz.models.Product.copy$default(com.abc.xyz.models.Product, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, 
2021-09-05 18:44:25.587 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.Date, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, java.lang.Object): [0xEEA] Rejecting invocation, expected 63 argument registers, method signature has 64 or more
2021-09-05 18:44:25.588 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime:  com.abc.xyz.models.Product com.abc.xyz.models.Product.copy(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java
2021-09-05 18:44:25.588 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: .lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.Date) failed to verify: com.abc.xyz.models.Product com.abc.xyz.models.Product.copy(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.
2021-09-05 18:44:25.588 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime: String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.Date): [0x341] Rejecting invocation, expected 63 argument registers, method signature has 64 or more (declaration of 'com.abc.xyz.models.Product' appears in /data/app/~~Wg7r1ES9wFNONoWdZ01ofg==/com.abc.xyz-2Baa-wi6FLDVeWfk7uP8kQ==/base.apk!classes5.dex)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ApiUtil.newInstance(ApiUtil.java:43)
2021-09-05 18:44:25.588 11239-11239/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:757)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:741)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:542)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:100)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:183)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:116)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:161)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:97)
        at com.abc.xyz.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment.getProductList$lambda-5(DashboardFragment.kt:396)
        at com.abc.xyz.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment.lambda$n8nng7NQijoblOO79lvVqrQrtT4(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.abc.xyz.ui.fragments.-$$Lambda$DashboardFragment$n8nng7NQijoblOO79lvVqrQrtT4.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Can somebody help me find my mistake, is it because I added many editText and TextViews?

Comment: When I removed some EidtText and TextViews, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue in my case was related to the excess number of EditText/TextView views. When I removed a few views, the error is gone and the app is working fine so far.